# How to make data visualization like this graph in r and which library is uesd?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two sets of tweets data.
What's the method to make data visualization by emotion based tweets and how to manage the tweets into scores and make a graph like this? Thank you.
[image: Here is the graph]

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Strongly assume it's ggplot with coord_polar. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_polar.html

Comment: When you say "manage the tweets into scores", we have no idea what format your data are in, what type of scores you want and what you have tried already. I'm afraid this really is too broad a question with too many missing debugging details to get a good answer on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is toy example, you will need to customize to your own specification:

```
df <- data.frame(
  hashtag = sample(c("Netflix", "PrimeVideo"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  emotion = sample(c("trust", "anger", "disgust", "joy", "suprise"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  value = sample(100, 100, replace = TRUE)
)


df %>%
  group_by(hashtag, emotion) %>%
  summarise(value = round(mean(value), 2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(emotion, value, color = hashtag, shape = hashtag)) +
  geom_point(size = 6) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), size = 3, color = "black", vjust = -1) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y = NULL, x = NULL, title = "Mean Percentage of Each Emotion per Tweet") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),
    legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14),
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      face = "bold", size = 12, color = RColorBrewer:::brewer.pal(n = 6, "YlOrBr")[2:6]
    )
  )
```

[image]

Also notice warning at the end.